# How to update or delete a data when the ID/primary was auto increment with php CodeIgniter Framework?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I can't update or delete my data on a table when the id/primary was auto increment, I have used a jquery but doesn't work, the data still can't update or delete

For view

```
 <a href="#modal_bagian" class="btn btn-default edit" data-toggle="modal" name="" id="edit_<?PHP echo $row->no_bagian; ?>">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Ubah
                            </a>

$(".edit").click(function() {
        $("#save").hide();
        $("#update").show();

        $("#no_bagian").attr("disabled", true);

        $("#form_bagian").attr("action", "<?PHP echo site_url(); ?>bagian/update");

        var id = this.id.substr(5);

        $("#no_bagian").val(id);
        $("#no_bagian_id").val(id);
        $("#nama_bagian").val($("#nama_bagian_" + id).val());
```

For model

```
public function update()
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_bagian 
                SET nama_bagian='".$this->get_nama_bagian()."' +1  
                WHERE no_bagian='".$this->get_no_bagian()."'";

        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

For controller

```
public function update()
    {
        $this->bagian_m->set_no_bagian($this->input->post("no_bagian_id"));
        $this->bagian_m->set_nama_bagian($this->input->post("nama_bagian"));


        $this->bagian_m->update();

        $data["status"] = "update_success";

        $this->load->view("bagian_v", $data);
    }
```

Comment: what you are trying to update? What these functions contains `get_nama_bagian(), get_no_bagian()` also provide the schema of your table.

Comment: no_bagian is an ID and i want to update or delete just nama_bagian because no_bagian is auto-increment

Comment: Make sure about the returned values from these both functions, might be the ID and value not set properly.